# How do I use "tcolorbox" to create an "Example" environment like the one shown below?

Tags: tcolorbox

[image]

How do I use "tcolorbox" package to create an "Example" environment like the picture shown below?

Comment: Welcome! Can you provide code showing what you've got so far? The package documentation includes lots of examples to get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the key points here are the following.

- You can define an `example` box so that the example itself is the *upper* part of the box while the solution is the *lower* part. Then, inside the box, you can use `\tcblower` to switch to the solution.
- You can use the key `before lower` to set the title of the solution part of the box.
- If you want to have the option to number the examples, you can use the `theorems` library to define the box with `\newtcbtheorem`. If you do this, the starred version of the box environment will be unnumbered.

So, I would use something like this

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcbtheorem{example}{Example}{
    theorem style=plain,
    arc=2mm,
    boxrule=.2mm,
    coltitle=black,
    colframe=blue!50!black,
    colback=blue!5!white,
    fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries,
    coltitle=blue!50!black,
    before lower={\textcolor{blue!50!black}{\textsf{\textbf{Solution:}}}\ },
}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{example*}{}
The result (1.40) can be obtained by direct Taylor series expansion of \(1/\lvert\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}'\rvert\). Try to finish it by yourself.
\tcblower
From the Taylor series:
\[
\Phi(\mathbf{x}) = \Phi(0) + \mathbf{x} \cdot \nabla\Phi(0) + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^3 \sum_{j=1}^3 x_i x_j \frac{\partial^2\Phi}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} + \cdots
\]
\end{example*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you big time

Comment: You don't need `theorems` to get numbering. I actually removed the numbering from the code I posted. cc. @2403Scott

Answer (score 0):

*Note that I think I ought not answer do-it-for-mes.*

You provide neither code nor any indication of what's causing you difficulty or, even, any hint as to which features of the box shown matter to you. The following may or may not be useful as a starting point. (But you could get at least as useful an example from the package documentation, with rather better commentary.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{xparse,skins,hooks}
\colorlet{bcol}{blue!50!black}
\NewTColorBox
{egbox}{ O {\linewidth} O {} }
{
  bocs,
  before upper app={\textsf{\textcolor{bcol}{Example: }}},
  before lower app={\textsf{\textcolor{bcol}{Solution: }}},
  halign lower=left,
  width=#1,
  #2,
}
\tcbset{%
  bocs/.style={%
    colframe=bcol,
    colback=gray!20,
    boxrule=.75mm,
    boxsep=.25mm,
    toptitle=.75mm,
    bottomtitle=.75mm,
    fonttitle=\sffamily,
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{egbox}
  Some stuff.
  \tcblower
  Some more stuff.
\end{egbox}
\begin{egbox}[.5\linewidth]
  Some stuff.
  \tcblower
  Some more stuff.
\end{egbox}
\begin{egbox}[.4\linewidth][colframe=red]
  Some stuff.
  \tcblower
  Some more stuff.
\end{egbox}
  
\end{document}
```

[image: boxes of various colours and widths]

Comment: Oh! My appology，I didn't look at the page just now. Thank you very much for your answer. In fact I did just go and check the information and found out that this is a very stupid question, I'm a newbie to latex, sorry for the intrusion

Comment: @2403Scott You don't need to apologise. I know lots of people don't really know their way around either the documentation or this site. What matters is that your next question is better ;). That you're apologising tells me it likely will be. If you post code showing what you've tried, it is also much easier to help. I happened to have something almost like this I'd already done. (This is why there is still a trace of Welsh in it.)